# How to send data received from external graphql api with nodejs to frontend (reactjs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql

This graphql api I found on the internet is showing cors error when I call it with fetch or apollo client from frontend, So I searched for a solution and I found out that if I call api from server, cors error will go away so I followed a basic tutorial about express and set up one, then call graphql api in my `server/index.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const rp = require("request-promise");
rp("https://.../graphql", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: `
          query {
              heroSearchByName(name: "John") {
                name
              }
          }
          `,
  }),
})
  .then((body) => {
    console.log(body); // result
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

const PORT = 4000;
const app = express();
console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${PORT} ...`);
app.listen(PORT);
```

Now I get the data back in my terminal but I don't know how to send those data back to my frontend which is in `frontend/App.js` to show data on my page. Can someone help me with this ? I am quite new to express and graphql so I might be doing it all wrong. Thanks

Comment: use it in your graphql server resolver, adapt received data to required shape (resolver return type)

Comment: Can you explain it in a more beginner way ? The below answer works but I think there should be better and advanced way to achieve it. I will also read on graphql resolver, thanks.

Comment: it was about own graphql server (apollo) with some queries forwarded to external graphql server ... probably https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware will be simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is something like this:

1. Frontend makes a request to the backend application.
2. Backend fetches the data from the GraphQL API and returns it to the client.

So on your express app just build a route

```js
const express = require("express");
const rp = require("request-promise");

app.post('/fetchData', function (req, res) {
rp("https://.../graphql", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: `
          query {
              heroSearchByName(name: "John") {
                name
              }
          }
          `,
  }),
})
  .then((body) => {
    res.send(body)
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });


})

const PORT = 4000;
const app = express();
console.log(`Server listening on http://localhost:${PORT} ...`);
app.listen(PORT);
``
```

Comment: more likely he still wants to use graphql client [on FE] and only 'proxy'/forward request to another server ... it would be nice to forward original query (from request body) and use `/graphql` post route

Comment: Thanks very much.